# Fetching value from a query result in the controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model, where I am running a query and selecting table field from my database, the result of this query is received in the controller. I am trying to extract the type_id, which is an id from this result and pass it to another function in the same model, this function than selects image paths from a database table against this type_id. But I am getting an error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Model

```
class Interior_listing_model extends CI_model
{
    public function interior_list()
  {
    //$query = $this->db->get('interior_testing');
    $query['resulty'] = $this->db->get_where('interior_testing', array('category_id' => 1),0,0);
    return $query['resulty']->result_array();

  }
public function image_list($type_id)
  {
$query1 = $this->db->get_where('interior_image_testing', array('type_id' => $type_id),3,0);
   return $query1->get()->row();
}

}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
        $data['articles']  = $this->interior->interior_list();
        $data['particles'] = $this->interior->image_list($data['articles']->type_id);
        // Load Interior Listing View
        $this->load->view("interior/interior",$data);
    }
```

In this controller at $data['articles']->type_id I am getting the error, mentioned above.

View

```
     <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
      span class="text-center"><?= $article->type ?></span><br/>
     <?php foreach ($particles as $particle): 
                    ?>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
                    <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle->image_path ?> " width="100%"> <!-- needs to be changed -->
                  </div> 
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: $data['articles']['type_id'] try this

Comment: Now it says, Message: Undefined index: type_id

Comment: $data['articles'][0]['type_id']. it is easy if you show me results using json_encoded

Comment: json_encoded-{"articles":[{"type_id":"2","name":"Raj Mondal","type":"Interior","location":"Kolkata","profile_pic":"ned_flanders.gif","cover_image":"cover2.jpeg","category_id":"1"},{"type_id":"3","name":"Rahul Bajaj","type":"Interior","location":"Pan India","profile_pic":"cat1.jpeg","cover_image":"potter.jpg","category_id":"1"}]}

Comment: Using $data['articles'][0]['type_id'] gives me Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::get()

Comment: $data['articles'][0]->type_id this will work

Comment: it gives me the same error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: just json_encode $data['articles'] this portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "return" statement on interior_list() is returning an array:

```
return $query['resulty']->result_array();
```

result_array() is a CI function that returns an array of rows, where each row is one record from the result.

So You're trying to access an object property called type_id but you're dealing with an array, not an object.

Since $data['articles'] could have two or more rows in it, you need to figure out what the expected result will be here.

For example, maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
$data['articles'] = $this->interior->interior_list();
foreach($data['articles'] as $idx => $article)
{
  $data['particles'] = array_merge($data['particles'], $this->interior->image_list($article["type_id"]));
}
```

Comment: After doing the above, the error is gone but I am not getting the images, as it says Message: Undefined variable: particles, it cannot read particles.

Comment: ["particles"]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#24 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "13" ["image_path"]=> string(11) "design1.jpg" ["type_id"]=> string(1) "3" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#25 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["image_path"]=> string(11) "design2.jpg" ["type_id"]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#26 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["image_path"]=> string(11) "design3.jpg" ["type_id"]=> string(1) "3" } } }

Comment: Even though there are values in particles, it says it cannot read particles.

Comment: Undefined variable: particles means you're trying to access particles via a variable called $particles. You have not shown us the code that does this, but that code would need to recognize the above structure and look for the particulars sub-array within each record of $data['articles']

Comment: I have added my view page

Comment: I updated the suggested code in the second code box. Try that out instead. It should merge all of the image_list() results into the $data["particles"] variable.

Answer (score 1):

At least two changes are needed.

In your model change

```
return $query['resulty']->result_array();
```

to

```
return $query['resulty']->result();
```

`result()` returns an array of objects where each object is a row from the query.

Because `$data['articles']` is an array of objects you need to reference which item in the array to use.

Change

```
$data['particles'] = $this->interior->image_list($data['articles']->type_id);
```

to

```
$data['particles'] = $this->interior->image_list($data['articles'][0]->type_id);
```

This will only use the first row of the model results. I suspect this won't be achieving everything you want. But it should stop the error.

Comment: It gives me the same error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Before I revise the answer please tell me, will `$this->interior->interior_list();` return several rows?